# What is the best way to avoid using goto statements in the pesudocode for an algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

What is the best way to avoid using goto statements when writing the pseudocode for an algorithm?

I want to avoid it and use another way to replace it. [image]

Comment: That’s a `while(true)` loop, with a `continue` statement inside the `if`. Isn’t it?

Comment: Why do you not want to use goto in your pseudocode? The point of pseudocode is to be readable as easily as possible. If goto helps with that (since apparently you can't even think of a simple way to write the code without goto), why would you not want to use goto?

Comment: What does $\mbox{close}$ mean? If it's a statement, it is never reached.

Comment: That code can only return `false` or loop forever. Is that really the intended behaviour? But, to answer your question, you get rid of `goto` statements in pseudocode in the same way as you would in any actual language.

Comment: this close statement is rather strange, When will it executed (never?) what is closed? Nothing was opened.

Answer (score 3):

In many cases, GOTO statement can be replaced by loops. For example, in your case, the inner loop is just "while string(i) = path(j), decrease both i and j", and the outer loop is a "loop forever", also known by the C idiom "while true".

Answer (score 0):

Whoever wrote that pseudo code decided to do flow control in the simplest possible way: Using labels and "goto". You'd have to use a different model for pseudocode, for example one which uses loops and "break" statements. Now you made your pseudocode "language" more complicated.